# can I use db_update to update a field ( appending a string to the current string in the database )

Tags: 7, database

Is it posible to do something like:

```
db_update('my_module_table')->fields( array('myfield' => <myfield> + 'newstring') );
```

Or do I have to load the field value first by using [db_select()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) ?

Maybe someway with [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) ?

Comment: you should do `db_update('my_module_table')->fields( array('myfield' => 'myfield'.'newstring'));`

Comment: @indrock this will not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still use `db_update()` just with an [`expression()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/function/UpdateQuery%3A%3Aexpression/7) instead of `fields()`, e.g.

```
db_update('my_module_table')
  ->expression('myfield', 'myfield + :newstring', array(':newstring' => 'Some string'))
  ->execute();
```

Although it strikes me that still wouldn't work as you're trying to concatenate strings (the `+` operator doesn't perform string concatenation as far as I know). This should do it:

```
db_update('my_module_table')
  ->expression('myfield', 'CONCAT(myfield, :newstring)', array(':newstring' => 'Some string'))
  ->execute();
```

Comment: this looks like an answer.

Comment: It does I'm trying this now...

Comment: works but not on an empty database field when it is run for the first time.

Comment: Hmm it should do (unless the field defaults to NULL, in which case I guess it wouldn't). You could get a bit more inventive: `->expression('myfield', 'IF(myfield IS NULL, :newstring, CONCAT(myfield, :newstring)), array(':newstring' => 'Some string'));`...but I haven't tried that

Comment: Yes field defaults to NULL. I'll figure it out with your last tip thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following,

```
db_update('my_module')
    ->condition(<condition>)
    ->expression('field', "concat(field, 'new String')")
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Any reason? Its a working example.

Comment: yes this works but not on an empty database field when it is run for the first time. I like @clive answer better and he was first as well.